# Partially solve merge conflicts and see the new diff/conflicts

Tags: git

Is it possible to partially fix a merge conflict and then see the new conflicting lines?

To be more precise; I have two branches, both with modifications to a file. But one of the files also have the wrong line-endings (CRLF).

This causes a merge conflict where all lines are considered to be in conflict. I would like to change the line-endings and then fix the other conflicts.

Comment: Hi. "I would like to change the line-endings and then fix the other conflicts."
What does prevent you from doing that? I'd try fixing the line-endings in the "broken" file, commit and push, and then merge the branches all together.

Comment: So you wish to make two commits? One for fixing the line-ending and one for merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

- Branch A has CRLF.
- Branch B does not have CRLF and it conflicts in other ways with Branch A.

On Branch A add one patch that corrects all line endings. Then merge Branch B into Branch A and resolve the merge conflicts.

Comment: yes, thank you. that should do the trick. In my mind I was stuck in the merge. But I could just do a `git reset --merge` first, right?

Comment: Er, the above is how I would solve the problem whereas `git reset --merge` isn't a command I use. Many ways to skin a cat! Do add another answer if you find a better way.

Comment: @BoboWieland - The command to abort the merge is `git merge --abort`.  `git reset --merge` is something completely different